# Custom Post Type 404 error when not logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type in WordPress that is always giving a 404 error whenever the admin is not logged in.

If I try to access the post while logged in as the admin the post loads with no 404 error.  If I try to access it when logged into any other account (non admin) or not logged in at all, I get the 404 error.

I know the common suggestion is to refresh the permalinks, but I have tried that and there were no changes.  Also, if it was a permalink issue I don't think it would work for the admin user either.

Anybody have any idea as to why a Custom Post type is only accessible when logged in to admin?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... had a massive 'DUH' moment.  Forgot to deactivate a plugin that was restricting access to the post before I began to test.